# VBA to generate a Single PDF with multiple pages instead of separate PDF files for each rows in excel

Tags: vba

I have the following Code that generates separate PDF Files for each rows of my excel sheet.

My goal is to generate a Single PDF file having a number of pages instead of seperate PDF Files.

Can any kind soul help me with this?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Create_PDF_Files()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim dsh As Worksheet
Dim tsh As Worksheet
Dim setting_Sh As Worksheet

Set dsh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Set tsh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Letter Template")
Set setting_Sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings")

Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.StatusBar = ""

Dim i As Integer
Dim File_Name As String

For i = 2 To dsh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            
        Application.StatusBar = i - 1 & "/" & dsh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1
        
        tsh.Range("C2").Value = dsh.Range("A" & i).Value
        tsh.Range("C3").Value = dsh.Range("D" & i).Value
        tsh.Range("C5").Value = dsh.Range("E" & i).Value
        tsh.Range("C6").Value = dsh.Range("F" & i).Value
        tsh.Range("C7").Value = dsh.Range("G" & i).Value
        tsh.Range("C8").Value = dsh.Range("H" & i).Value
        tsh.Range("C9").Value = dsh.Range("I" & i).Value
        tsh.Range("C10").Value = dsh.Range("J" & i).Value
        tsh.Range("D12").Value = dsh.Range("K" & i).Value
        
        File_Name = dsh.Range("B" & i).Value & "_" & dsh.Range("C" & i).Value & "_" & dsh.Range("K" & i).Value & ".pdf"
        tsh.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Range("F4").Value & "\" & File_Name

Next i
    
    Application.StatusBar = ""
    MsgBox "PDF files generated successfully."
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The line starting `tsh.ExportAsFixedFormat...` is inside the `For... next` loop. This is why it is generating a new PDF for each file.

There are three approaches you could try:

1. Move that line below the `next` statement, and adjust your code so that your accumulating variable is fed into an overall variable, which you then export.
2. Run it like you are now, but add a step at the end to combine all the generated files into one PDF.
3. Find a different export function that generates a PDF page rather than file, and can aggregate at the end.

Comment: Dear Sir,

Thank you for your response. 

After trying the 1st approach: only one PDF is generated fine but it contains only the last row of data of my excel file.

Comment: You have done this bit "Move that line below the `next` statement,"... but you also need to do this bit "and adjust your code so that your accumulating variable is fed into an overall variable, which you then export."

Comment: Can you please help me with what specific adjustments do I need to incorporate ?

Comment: There are a few similar questions you could refer to and adapt, such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30164466/how-to-export-multiple-ranges-to-a-single-pdf, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13804102/exporting-multiple-pages-to-pdf-in-a-specific-order